# overflow-x for the div in the wrapper

Tags: html, css

Here is the rough structure of the web-site:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
          <div class="report">
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now I do have next CSS:

```
.wrapper {
     width: 75%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So the question is, how can I prevent div with report class from overflowing div with wrapper class? In case of overflowing I want to add scroll to the div with report class.

Right now the "report" div just dynamicly extends width of the wrapper.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow: auto;` to add a scrollbar only when and where scrolling is necessary. If the viewport is big enough, no scrollbars will appear. If the viewport is not wide enough but is tall enough, it will create a scrollbar only on the y-axis.

See [this Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) on `overflow` for more info.

Comment: I don't know why, but it's now working in my case. The "report" is still extending the width of wrapper.

Comment: @vminof you would need to post more comprehensive code for us to determine the problem. Perhaps with filler data/content if yours is sensitive/proprietary.

Comment: "The "report" is still extending the width of wrapper" that's not called overflow right? that's the default behaviour of block elements.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/gjSS8/) 
If you followed the answer the wrapper won't overflow unless you've other css which you haven't shared. Or you might be confusing the term `overflow` with something else!